# how can to pass the userid of the user is currently logged in as a parameter in sql with c# net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

Hi I am trying to pass the user ID of the user who is logged in as a parameter in a SQL query for .net(c#) web form.

to display the ID of who is currently logged in use

```
<%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() %>
```

and I want to pass this ID into "@PARA1"

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1"
        ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT orders.OrderID, order_details.ProductID,
        order_details.Price, orders.AddressLine1, orders.TownCity, orders.PostCode, orders.AddressLine2 
        FROM orders INNER JOIN order_details 
        ON orders.OrderID = order_details.OrderID 
        INNER JOIN AspNetUsers ON orders.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id
        WHERE AspNetUsers = @PARA1">
        
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="PARA1" = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId />
         </SelectParameters>
```

the error that I get is

> Literal content ('<asp:Parameter Name="PARA1" = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() />') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection'.

I what would be the best way for me to do this?

Comment: this does not work I get a new error

>Parser Error Message: Literal content ('<asp:Parameter Name="PARA1" = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId () />') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection'.

Comment: Your page markup is completely invalid in the parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can only add value in the code behind

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
     e.Command.Parameters["@PARA1"].Value = ....;
}
```

and fix the page

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ......
OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
<SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="PARA1" Type="String"/>
 </SelectParameters>
```